# Column to display day of week

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, sharepoint-calendar

I am using the following formula to calculate the day of week based off of the Start Date column:

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY([Start Date]),"dddd")
```

The problem is that when I create the event on the calendar view I'm getting the day that ends up being displayed in list view is 1 day prior.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this is occurring?

[image]

If I go into the list view and edit the date though it will recalculate to the correct day of week.

Comment: Try using =TEXT([Start Date],"dddd")

Answer (score 1):

Try using your formula like below:

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY([Start Date]+1),"dddd")
```

**official documentation**:

1. [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weekday-function-f0aa7aa6-fad7-4e41-aab9-3e77a133f0be).

Comment: This works but it makes the list unstable. If a user accidentally goes into list view and edits the dates it will then calculate incorrectly and be ahead one day instead of behind.

Comment: Have you tried editing the list item?

Comment: Yes, when I edit the list item using the formula you provided the day turns to Friday in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below formula,

=TEXT([Start Date],"dddd")

I just tried this function and it gives me the correct weekday.

Answer (score 0):

What is the return type of your calculated column? I tested with your formula and calendar view does not have any issue. You can try the same formula with a new column and other lists to see if the issue persists.

Comment: The return type is 'single line text'

Comment: @JoeCambareri Does the formula works correctly in a new list?

Comment: No, it doesn’t work correctly in a new list or in a different column on the same list.

Comment: @JoeCambareri, if the issue is site-level or tenant level, you may open a service request to have a check on your tenant.